# OpenVPN fails on different port

Tags: networking, router, vpn, firewall, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN setup with a linux server and windows client in mode-server with tap and over UDP. Everything works with port 1194. But I want to change to port 500.

On my firewall I forward port 500 UDP to the appropriate router. To prove that my network setup is correct, I use on the server: `nc -l -u -p 500` and on the client `echo hello | nc -u server 500`.

Sure enough, on the server:

```
nc -l -u -p 500
hello
```

Now I add `port 500` lines to both client and server config and suddenly the client pretents it cannot be reached any (I should check the network connectivity):

```
Mon Apr 25 19:21:37 2016 UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]
Mon Apr 25 19:21:37 2016 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]server:500
Mon Apr 25 19:22:37 2016 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Mon Apr 25 19:22:37 2016 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
```

But this is stupid, apart from the fact that UDP over 500 works perfectly well with netcat, also the server sees the connection request but fails:

```
Apr 26 04:56:49 radix ovpn-server[465865]: client:44294 LZO compression initialized
Apr 26 04:56:49 radix ovpn-server[465865]: read UDPv4 [EHOSTUNREACH]: No route to host (code=113)
Apr 26 04:56:52 radix ovpn-server[465865]: read UDPv4 [EHOSTUNREACH]: No route to host (code=113)
Apr 26 04:56:55 radix ovpn-server[465865]: read UDPv4 [EHOSTUNREACH]: No route to host (code=113)
Apr 26 04:56:55 radix ovpn-server[465865]: read UDPv4 [EHOSTUNREACH]: No route to host (code=113)
Apr 26 04:57:03 radix ovpn-server[465865]: read UDPv4 [EHOSTUNREACH]: No route to host (code=113)
Apr 26 04:57:19 radix ovpn-server[465865]: read UDPv4 [EHOSTUNREACH]: No route to host (code=113)
```

I think I can exclude any network related issues.
Also, please note that the connection worked perfectly but started to fail at some random point.

As reference, I add my config files:

client:

```
client
remote server
rport 500
proto udp
resolv-retry infinite
dev tap
dev-node "OpenVPN"
tap-sleep 3
ca ca.crt
cert client1.crt
key client1.key
comp-lzo
comp-noadapt
ns-cert-type server
mute 5
verb 2
```

server:

```
mode server
tls-server
keepalive 5 30
local 192.168.200.1
proto udp
port 500
persist-key
user nobody
group nogroup
dev tap0
ca "/etc/openvpn/ca.crt"
cert "/etc/openvpn/server.crt"
key "/etc/openvpn/server.key"
dh "/etc/openvpn/dh1024.pem"
mute-replay-warnings
client-to-client
comp-lzo
comp-noadapt
```

Comment: Do you have selinux enabled on the Linux Server? It may be causing the failures. Try running `sudo setenforce permissive` temporarily and see if the problem goes away. You can run `sudo semanage port --list | grep 500` to see if selinux is managing that port. If selinux isn't involved, it maybe related to root access being required to use ports under 1024 in linux. Its possible that some component of openvpn is running under a regular users permissions and it is getting blocked - try using an arbitrary port over 1024 with openvpn and see if that works.

Comment: Indeed, that works (e.g. 5001). However, the reason why I want 500 is that it is used by IPSec and hence more likely not being blocked by restrictive IPS. I do not have SELinux installed. The permission argument is also untrue: I leave everything the same on the server (i.e., port 5001), just change on the client to 500 and change my firewall to forward from 500 to 5001 (instead of 5001 to 5001). Problem is there again.

Comment: Alright, that brings me to the solution: Changing on the client to 501 (and router) to 501 works. `netstat -a -n -o` on Windows shows that svchost.exe is listening on UDP 0.0.0.0:500. Is is the service IKEEXT (IKE and AuthIP IPsec Keying Modules). Alright, then my question: WHY would this matter? And why does the connection with netcat work without any problems?

Comment: I was just looking into that; Windows reserves port 500 udp for 'IPsec Internet Security Association and Key Management Protocol (ISAKMP) (UDP port 500)'. Explanation is here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/83201

Comment: As to the why, I'd guess that it's not Windows blocking openvpn from getting the port based on your symptoms, but either taking the port back after some time or openvpn receiving packets intended for IPSec, and things go off the rails.